# Rainmeter Calc always returns 0

Tags: rainmeter

While designing a Rainmeter skin I noticed that none of the Calc measures were working, so I created a simple test skin that looks like the following.

```
[Rainmeter]
Update=1000
AccurateText=1

[Metadata]
Name=
Author=
Information=
Version=
License=Creative Commons Attribution - Non - Commercial - Share Alike 3.0

[Variables]
TestVar=4

[TestCalc]
Measure=Calc
Formula=#TestVar# * 2
; Also tried not using variables.

[MeterString]
Meter=String
Text=Number: [TestCalc]
AntiAlias=1
FontFace=Segoe UI
FontColor=255, 255, 255
FontSize=20
```

The text from `[MeterString]` is ALWAYS `Number: 0` no matter what.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Add DynamicVariables=1 to [MeterString]

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the current `Text` with these two lines.

```
MeasureName=TestCalc
Text=Number: %1
```

For one reason or another, section variables (`[TestCalc]`) can't be combined with another string. `%1` is replaced with `MeasureName` in `String`s

[Documentation](https://docs.rainmeter.net/manual/meters/string/)

Comment: Omg I forgot I ever asked this question. I think I stopped working on this. When I have the opportunity I'll test it out. Thanks for responding regardless!